# ruby caesar cipher byte or char manipulation

Tags: ruby, caesar-cipher

Hello I am trying to create a caesar cipher in ruby but i am stuck.
I am able to split the string into single chars and put into array.  then made a new hash and stored the char => byte number.

in the hash, h has a value of 104.  i would like to change the value + 5.  if value is 109,  how do i also change h to m? (104*start, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109*end) (h*start, i, j, k, l, *end)

```
str = "hello world"

str_array = str.chars.to_a

str_hash = Hash.new

str_array.each do |char|
  str_hash[char]= char.bytes
end

print str_hash

{"h"=>[104], "e"=>[101], "l"=>[108], "o"=>[111], " "=>[32], "w"=>[119], "r"=>[114], "d"=>[100]}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's a little unclear which is the bit you're stuck on. What did you try to get it working? it won't break anything to just have a go, even if it doesn't work. Often what you think of will Just Work, and if not, the error message will tell you a lot.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the welcome.  i will try to clarify.

Comment: in the hash, h has a value of 104.  i would like to change the value + 5.  if value is 109,  how do i also change h to m? (104*start, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109*end) (h*start, i, j, k, l, *end)

Comment: So what happened when you tried adding that code and running it? ie: just try adding 5 to h and seeing what happens!

Comment: ok i did that, and it make me start thinking.  I realized if i can convert a char into byte.  i just need the command to do the reverse.  i found the 2 commands they are
.ord => converts char into byte
.chr => converts byte to character

thanks!!  i was struggling with this for a while

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a bit of overkill. Normally you would generate the cipher at first and after that do lookup as you are translating.
Ruby also has a rotate method on arrays which does exactly what you need.
See below for a code sample that encode "hello world"

```
original = ('a'..'z').to_a
codes = original.rotate(5)
cipher = {}
original.each_with_index do |c,i|
  cipher[c] = codes[i]
end

str = "hello world"
encoded_str = []
str.split('').each do |c|
  if cipher.key(c)
    encoded_str << cipher[c]
  else
    encoded_str << c
  end
end

puts encoded_str.join('')
```